# How to add primitive type 'String'?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'd like to use EA for a PHP project. I was about adding attributes to my classes and found out that there is no type 'string', which actually is a primitive type in PHP. Where can I add it (in EA 12)? Or do I need to create a class String?

I guess this question is not restricted to PHP, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Project|Settings|Code Engineering Datatypes...`and select your language (or add it if it doesn't exists yet).

Then add the datatypes
[image]

Comment: That works. However, is it wise to it? Everything is 'var' in EA for PHP. But if I want to give my attributes an 'expected type', how else should I do it? Via comments? With this approach I would have to define int, float,... as well. So now I'm a bit unsure.

Comment: @robsch I guess it depends on what you want to use it for. If it is for code generation then you will first need to check if the generated code it what you expect it to be. If it's only to serve as analysis/documentation then this seems fine. You can add all primitive types you seem fit.

Comment: Is this still the correct solution in 2019? Is there some way to "import" all default datatypes (e.g. String, Date, DateTime, etc.) that Java supports in the latest version of Enterprise Architect 14.1?

Answer (score -1):

The solution in Enterprise Architect 14.1 is to click configure-> settings-> Code Engineering Datatypes, and then add the data types you want.
[image]

Comment: Well, I was wrong with 7 minutes. It's 6 years after Geerts post.

Comment: btw: V14 is now 2 years old. Current version is V16